# Algebraic Integers of a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Suppose my ring is $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i2\pi/p^2}]$. I wish to prove that the algebraic integers are ${\sum_{n = 0}^{p^2-p-1}a_{n}e^{i2n\pi/p^2}}$ where each $a_{k} \in \mathbb{Z}$. I see why thus finite sums are algebraic integers: every integer is algebraic integer and the complex exponent is a root of $1+x^p+x^{2p} + ... + x^{p(p-1)}$ so it is algebraic so the the sum is algebraic integer because the algebraic integers form a ring. How do I show that every algebraic integer in my ring has this form? That is why must each $a_{n}$ be an integer?

Comment: I assume your sum is supposed to be ${\sum_{k = 0}^{p^2-p-1}a_{k}e^{i2k\pi/p^2}}$?

Comment: Ehr... first, your sum is indexed by $n$, but $n$ never appears, whereas $k$ does. Also, all factors are multiplied by the same exponential.  And finally, if you mean the powers of that element, what you are giving is the description of all *elements* of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i2\pi/p^2}]$. Since $e^{i2\pi/p^2}$ is an algebraic integer, the module it generates also consists of algebraic integers. Do you mean to ask why this ring is the ring of all algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p^2})$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the result saying that for any number field $K$ with ring of algebraic integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, then given any subring $B\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ and any $\alpha\in B$ generating $K$ as a field with minimal polynomial $f$, we have $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq \frac{1}{f'(\alpha)}B$?

Comment: @EthanMacBrough No i am not familiar; how would this help with my proof?

Comment: @user758469 as far as I know the only reasonably simple proofs of this fact use the result I stated. Using $B=\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/p^2}]$ and $\alpha = e^{2\pi i/p^2}$ one gets that the ring of integers is contained in $\frac{1}{p^l}\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/p^2}]$ for some $l$, and then you use Eisenstein polynomials to show that $l=0$.

Comment: @EthanMacBrough How do you get from B to the fact that the ring of integers is contained in $1/p^{l}*\mathbb{Z}[e^{2i\pi/p^2}]$?

Comment: @user758469 this comes from the result I stated. For $\alpha = e^{2\pi i/p^2}$, $f'(\alpha)$ is an algebraic integer whose only prime divisors are the prime lying above $p$.

Comment: But why is that truefor any number field K with ring of algebraic integers $O_{K}$, then given any subring B⊆$O_{K}$ and any α∈B generating K as a field with minimal polynomial f, we have $O_{K}$⊆$\frac{1}{f′(α)}$B?? Could you explain why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106455/discussion-between-user758469-and-ethan-macbrough).